# OKTA SSO: Getting HTTP Error 405- Method Not Allowed

Tags: single-sign-on, okta

I am looking for single sign on using Okta as Identity Provider. But during SSO it gives me 405 Method not allowed with "**Requested method POST not supported**" message. It works as expected with my other Okta instance with same configuration. Is there any way to allow POST SSO request for Okta?

Please refer the below images for reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8VPo.png)